# How to solve firestore pagination startAfter issue android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

i have one `RecyclerView` which contains user data i need to set pagination but it's not working.
i am following steps as per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query) but it's not working it always gives me 0 record.

this is what I done so far

```
var lastResult: DocumentSnapshot? = null
fun getAllAstrologer(paginationSize: Long) {

    if (networkHelper.isNetworkConnected()) {
        _getAllAstrologerResponse.value = Resource.loading(null)
        var ref = if (lastResult == null) {
            userRepository.getAllAstrologerUser()
                .orderBy(Constants.FIELD_FULL_NAME)
                .limit(paginationSize)
        } else {
            userRepository.getAllAstrologerUser()
                .orderBy(Constants.FIELD_FULL_NAME)
                .startAfter(lastResult)
                .limit(paginationSize)
        }
        ref.get().addOnSuccessListener {

            var userModel = AstrologerUsersList.getUserArrayList(it, "")
            MyLog.e(TAG, "data == " + userModel.size)
            if (it.size() > 0) {
                lastResult = it.documents.last()
            }
            _getAllAstrologerResponse.postValue(Resource.success(userModel))

        }
    } else {
        _getAllAstrologerResponse.value =
            Resource.error(Constants.MSG_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION, null)
    }

}
```

in `RecyclerView` i set this code on in scroll

```
var paginationSize = 10
with(binding.rvAstrologer) {
            val mLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
            layoutManager = mLayoutManager
            itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
            adapter = AstrologerAdapter(
                context, mAstrologerList,
                object : AstrologerAdapter.ViewHolderClicks {
                    override fun onBookNowClickItem(
                        model: AstrologerUserModel,
                        position: Int
                    ) {
                        //click of recyclerview item
                       
                    }

                    override fun onProfileClickItem(model: AstrologerUserModel, position: Int) {
                    }
                }
            )

            addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                    val lastVisible = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1
                    val visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()+1
                    if (visibleItemCount == mLayoutManager.itemCount) {
                        viewModel.getAllAstrologer(paginationSize.toLong())
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

**I am always getting 0 item on the scroll of `RecyclerView` while requesting 2nd-page data.**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo i am not getting any error on loading new record it's always giving me 0 record

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem in your code at first glance, but I think that [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firestore-using-jetpack-compose-76b4c0b5acd5), might help.

Comment: i am using as per docs article required paging 3 library and all extra things.

Comment: Same as Alex, the code looks fine at first glance. I recommend setting breakpoints on all lines, running in the debugger, and then checking each variable to see when it goes wrong. If you find more debug information that way, we may be able to help better.